# How to change a class' background color on-scroll on fullpage.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullpage.js

I have a div with a class .header, I want its background color to change to transparent on scroll. How can I do that on javascript? I use fullpage.js plugin and have only 2 sections btw.

```
<body>
  <div class="header">

      CONTENTS HERE
        
</div>
<div id="fullPage">
  <div class="section bg">
        
       CONTENTS HERE

  </div>

  <div class="section aboutme">
     
      CONTENTS HERE

  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

```
.header {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
text-align: center;
padding: 8px 15px;
overflow: hidden;
min-height: 46px;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
z-index: 999;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [fullpage.js state classes](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#state-classes-added-by-fullpagejs) or the [callbacks](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#callbacks) to accomoplish that.

Here's an example using fullpage state classes:
https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/VwbxbYR

```css
.fp-viewing-1-0 button{
    background: blue;
}
```

`fp-viewing-1-0` basically means fullpage.js is on the 2nd section and the 1st slide.
So, both sections and slides use a 0 based index.

Here's another example using callbacks:
https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/XbPNQv

More examples in the [the fullpage.js documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js)

```js
    afterLoad: function(origin, destination, direction){
        var loadedSection = this;

        //using index
        if(origin.index == 2){
            alert("Section 3 ended loading");
        }

        //using anchorLink
        if(origin.anchor == 'secondSlide'){
            alert("Section 2 ended loading");
        }
    }
```